# cannot filter by an added field in django

Tags: django

I want to filter by "status" which is an added field but it does not work:

```
serial_number_list = TestSerialNumber.objects.filter(test_pool = test_pool, status='rejected')
```

I get this error:

**Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are: id, serial_number, test_pool, testresult, testrun**

This is my model class:

```
class TestSerialNumber(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.ForeignKey("core.SerialNumber", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    test_pool = models.ForeignKey("TestPool", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial_number.serial_number

    def panel_code(self):
        return self.serial_number.panel.panel_code

    def status(self):
        try:
            test_result = self.testresult_set.latest('report')
        except TestResult.DoesNotExist:
            return 'unknown'
        else:
            return test_result.test_status.name
```

Also, when exporting to json, i get just the fields: serial_number and test_pool, just the ids and not the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `status` is not a field, it is a method.

Comment: See [this][1] link on how to use a custom manager.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685037/django-filter-query-based-on-custom-function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it you have to create a field with name "status"

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'rejected'),
    (2, 'blabla'),
)

status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I don't think that's accurate. `status` in the code comes from the most recent item in a Foreign Key relationship. While you could start tracking a denormalized field every time a related `TestResult` is added or updated via a signal, a custom manager or raw sql is probably preferable.

Comment: Yes I agree! This case is only an example when the object normally will not change and just for filtering...

Answer (score 0):

By the structure of your code that you have provided, `status` is not a field its a method. So if you want to get the status for and object you need to filter it out first and then you can access the method that will return its `status` for that object.

```
serial_number_list = TestSerialNumber.objects.filter(test_pool = test_pool)
print serial_number_list[0].status # as filter return a list
```

this will give you the status for that object.

The error `Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are:id, serial_number, test_pool, testresult, testrun` occurs when you try to access the model with a invalid field, by invalid I mean the field that doesnot exist in the `model` or the `database`