# How to exclude a list of numbers from a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of integers:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have a model, MyModel, with primary keys ranging 1 to 1000

I would like to exclude the models with primary keys in the list 'numbers' from MyModel during a QuerySet:

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(pk in numbers)
```

The above doesn't work.

What's the best way to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : Filter query based on custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685037/django-filter-query-based-on-custom-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for a field being in a list with the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) filter

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(pk__in=numbers)
```